# Swift CLLocationManager: How to change status from "Don't Allow" to "Allow" by popping up Authorization Dialog again

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

CLLocationManager `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` Authorization dialog works only for once.
How to change status from "Don't Allow" to "Allow" by popping up the same Authorization Dialog again.

Comment: I think you can only pop up a dialog one time

Comment: if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

} , with the help of this code, u can do manually.

Comment: What is the beast/recommended approach then, if we can pop up authorization only once, and after checking locationServicesEnabled?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/ I believe this tutorial will help you understand more about `CLLocationManager`

Comment: So UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is the key. Thanks @dvp.petrov

Comment: @dvp.petrov see if you can post your comment as answer? I shall accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as you already figured it out you can check for `authorizationStatus`. Once you check that the user has denied you access, you can always use custom alert (dialog) for telling the user, he/she needs to permit your app to use Location. A good way to do that is adding Alert option that navigates him to the Settings of your app, as you have found out, you can do that with:  `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`.

A good tutorial on this subject is: http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

Also, I would recommend you to take your time and look at the Apple doc site (this always helps me see the big picture): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager

Answer (score 0):

You can't I don't believe, if the user has denied your app access to their location you have to instruct them to turn it on in their settings.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the entry from settings, so that we can go over again?

Comment: No, you have to instruct them to open settings & allow access to your app.